# How to understand part and partition of ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I see that clickhouse created multiple directories for each partition key.

[Documentation says](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/table_engines/custom_partitioning_key/) the directory name format is: *partition name*, *minimum number of data block*, *maximum number of data block* and *chunk level*. For example, the directory name is `201901_1_11_1`.

I think it means that the directory is a part which belongs to partition *201901*, has the blocks from *1* to *11* and is on level *1*. So we can have another part whose directory is like `201901_12_21_1`, which means this part belongs to partition *201901*, has the blocks from *12* to *21* and is on level *1*.

So I think partition is split into different parts.
Am I right?

Comment: Not - partition is not split to parts, a partition is collected from parts. 
Originally parts are generated by INSERT (so that pretty important to follow the [insert rule](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/insert_into/#performance-considerations)) and periodically merged to have a few large parts (ideally have just one part per partition). Look at this explanation: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/3174#issuecomment-423435071

Comment: @vladimir Thank you for your reply. According to your answer, in a part directory, we can have several partitions and every partition has its own directory in the part directory. And when we read data, we need to check every partition range in the part to select which to read.  Do I understand that right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Parts -- pieces of a table which stores rows. One part = one folder with columns.

Partitions are virtual entities. They don't have physical representation. But you can say that these parts belong to the same partition.

---

Select does not care about partitions.

Select is not aware about partitioning keys.

BECAUSE each part has special files minmax_{PARTITIONING_KEY_COLUMN}.idx
These files contain min and max values of these columns in this part.
Also this minmax_ values are stored in memory in a (c++ vector) list of parts.

```
create table X (A Int64, B Date, K Int64,C String) 
Engine=MergeTree partition by (A, toYYYYMM(B)) order by K;

insert into X values (1, today(), 1, '1');

cd /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/X/1-202002_1_1_0/
ls -1 *.idx
minmax_A.idx   <-----
minmax_B.idx   <-----
primary.idx

SET send_logs_level = 'debug';
select * from X where A = 555;

(SelectExecutor): MinMax index condition: (column 0 in [555, 555])
(SelectExecutor): Selected 0 parts by date
```

SelectExecutor checked in-memory part list and found 0 parts because minmax_A.idx = (1,1) and this select needed (555, 555).

CH does not store partitioning key values.

So for example toYYYYMM(today()) = 202002 but this 202002 is not stored in a part or anywhere.

minmax_B.idx stores (18302, 18302) `(2020-02-10 == select toInt16(today()))`

Comment: I think minmax index is one of the skip indices. I see you create table without specifying the minmax index and the MergeTree will create minmax index by default？

Comment: @GOGO you are mistaken. This is how partitioning and partition pruning works. I found that out and made my own notice for myself using clickHouse release 1.1.54394, 2018-07-12, which was released 2 years before skip indexes invented.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, one part belongs to one partition? And the parition range of every part is recorded in the part directory name?

Comment: @GOGO partition encoded in the part name (folder name). 1-202002_1_1_0 -- 1-202002 -- partition (name). 1_1 -- blocks range (1 - just a sequenced number -- uniq block identifier). 0 -- level (0 insert -- never merged) https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/table_engines/custom_partitioning_key/

Comment: Tables created with old  (depricated) syntax  tables have another part naming and part (folder) name containes date ranges 20200215_20200215_1_1_0

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had used groupArray() and arrayEnumerate() for ranking in Populate. I thought that Populate can run query with new data on the partition (in my case: toStartOfDay(Date)), the total sum of new inserted data is correct but the groupArray() function is doesn't work correctly.

I think it's happened because when insert one Part, CH will groupArray() and rank on each Part immediately then merging Parts in one Partition, therefore i wont get exactly the final result of groupArray() and arrayEnumerate() function.
Summary, Merge

> [groupArray(part_1) + groupArray(part_2)] is different from
>   groupArray(Partition)

with

> Partition=part_1 + part_2

The solution that i tried is insert new data as one block size, just like using groupArray() to reduce the new data to the number of rows that is lower than max_insert_block_size=1048576. It did correctly but it's hard to insert new data of 1 day as one Part because it will use too much memory for querying when populating the data of 1 day (almost 150Mn-200Mn rows).

But do u have another solution for Populate with groupArray() for new inserting data, such as force CH to use POPULATE on each Partition, not each Part after merging all the part into one Partition?