# What is the actual use of partitions in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

It says partitions make it easier to drop or move data so that there is hit only on limited data. In various blogs it is suggested to use month as a partitioning key (`toYYYYMM(date)`). In many places it is also suggested to not have more than a couple of partitions. I am using clickhouse as a database to store time series data which do not undergo frequent deletions. What would be the advisable partitioning key for timeseries data of high volume? Does there have to be one if I do not want to perform deletes frequently?

<strike>In production I noticed that startup was very slow and I was suspecting that having too many partitions is the culprit. So I decided to test it out by inserting time-series data fresh into a table (which created >2300 partitions for ~20Bil rows) by selecting data from another table (so that it doesn't have an opportunity to optimize the table). Immediately I dropped the original table and tried a restart. It finished fast in about 10s. This is in complete opposite to what I observed in production with 800GB+ of data (with many databases and tables as opposed to my test node which had only one table).</strike>

Edit: As it was pointed out, I mixed up parts and partitions. Regarding startup time of clickhouse being affected, I'd better post another question.

Comment: Do not confuse parts and partitions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142967/how-to-understand-part-and-partition-of-clickhouse

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/#partition-by

Comment: optimization happens during insertion as well

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty common question, and for disclosure, I work at ClickHouse.

Partitions are particularly useful when you have timeseries data, as you noted. When determining the number of partitions, we often recommend a few guidelines:

The use of partitioning should be determined by a couple of questions as to why you're using them:

- are you generally going to query only a single partition? For example, if your queries are often for results within a one day or one month period, it could make sense to partition at that period duration
- are you wanting to "tier" or set a TTL on your data such that once the partition reaches an age of X (e.g., 91 days old, 7 months old), you want to do something special with it? (e.g., TTL to lower cost tier storage, backup and delete from ClickHouse, etc.)
- We often recommend to keep the number of partitions less than around 100. Up to 1000 partitions can work, but it is suboptimal and will have some performance impact at the filesystem and index/memory sizes, which can impact startup time insert/query time

Given these guidelines, hoping that helps with your question. It is probably most common to partition at the day or month, but since ClickHouse can manage large tables quite easily, might want to move towards fewer partitions if possible - partitioning by month probably most common.

I didn't fully understand your test results so please feel free to expand. 2300 partitions sounds like too many but might work, just with some performance implications. Reducing your number of partitions (and therefore increasing the partition size) seems like a good recommendation.

Comment: Most of my queries are going to be for the past day or week of data, so it does make sense to partition on month (as advised) so that there is a hit on a single partition. Then why is it frequently mentioned that partitions are not the way to go for speeding up queries? I am already having the data ordered by time. Is it intended to have ordering as the primary way to speed up queries and partitioning as an additional improvement?

Comment: Partitions do not speed up queries. Having an efficient primary key (sorting key) helps improve performance the most. This is mentioned in the documentation here - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/custom-partitioning-key/

Comment: Thom says it makes sense to partition time-series data on month so that only limited data is searched. Does this imply that partitioning speeds up queries? if yes, then why is it being discouraged? if not, then why is it being advised?

Comment: "Then why is it frequently mentioned that partitions are not the way to go for speeding up queries?" To discourage newbies to invent very granular partitions. Partition pruning does improve performance, BUT it's not a purpose of partitions.